# How to debug job failures in apache yarn

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

i have hadoop apache yarn (2.4.0) multinode cluster with 2 datanodes and 1 master node. My setup works fine but when i run my hadoop word count example which came in the package . my job stops at `14/08/28 15:44:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1409220779657_0001`
How to debug debug the problem regarding this ... what is the error behind this ...
Note : I used below command to run the word count example

```
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.0.jar wordcount /input /output
```

Machine : Ubuntu server 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks has a good post on logging under YARN at: http://hortonworks.com/blog/simplifying-user-logs-management-and-access-in-yarn/

If you have *yarn.log-aggregation-enable* set to *true* in yarn-site.xml then you can retrieve all relevant logs for an application by running:

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>
```

(note: the application ID will match the job ID, so you would use application_1409220779657_0001)